# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone help with the following code?

I'm trying to get data from the database colum to the datagridview...
I'm getting error over here "Dim sql_1 As String = "SELECT * FROM item where item_id = '" + DataGridView_stockout.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() + "'""

```
Private Sub DataGridView_stockout_CellMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView_stockout.CellMouseClick
    Dim i As Integer = Stock_checkDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0
    Dim thiscur_stok As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=MBTHQ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=stock_check;Integrated Security=True")
    ' Sql Query 

    Dim sql_1 As String = "SELECT * FROM item where item_id = '" + DataGridView_stockout.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() + "'"
    ' Create Data Adapter
    Dim da_1 As New SqlDataAdapter(sql_1, thiscur_stok)
    ' Fill Dataset and Get Data Table
    da_1.Fill(Stock_checkDataSet1, "item")
    Dim dt_1 As DataTable = Stock_checkDataSet1.Tables("item")
    If i >= DataGridView_stockout.Rows.Count Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Sorry, DataGridView_stockout doesn't any row at index " & i.ToString())
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If 1 >= Stock_checkDataSet1.Tables.Count Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Sorry, Stock_checkDataSet1 doesn't any table at index 1")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If i >= Stock_checkDataSet1.Tables(1).Rows.Count Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Sorry, Stock_checkDataSet1.Tables(1) doesn't any row at index " & i.ToString())
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Stock_checkDataSet1.Tables(1).Columns.Contains("os") Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Sorry, Stock_checkDataSet1.Tables(1) doesn't any column named 'os'")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'DataGridView_stockout.Item("cs_stockout", i).Value = Stock_checkDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("os")
    Dim ab As String = Stock_checkDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString()
End Sub
```

I keep on getting the error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
I dont know where I'm going wrong.
Help really appreciated!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

```
Stock_checkDataSet1.Tables(1)
```

I think you need to use a 0 index.

Comment: Thanks for response. But where should i make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Start the debugger and turn on break on exception, you'll see the exact point where the exception occurs then.

Comment: Well, did tried using debugger, but couldn't get where exactly 'm going wrong.
What i actuli want is when i click on curent stock column it should get the stock as per the item id inserted.

And for that i wrote the sql as

select * from item where itemid = '" + datagridview.currentcell.value +"'

But how can i reference on click on current stock column to run the query to get the value from the database as per the itemid typed on the itemid column.

Help really appreciated.